# Form validation is not working showing IndexOf, match, search not defined error

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I'm working on js form validation here getting this error IndexOf is undefined and I added `var useremail = ''` error will go but and the form fields are not validated. Can anyone point me in the right direction what might be the issue. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```js
class Registrationform {
  constructor() {
    this.initializeElements();
  }
  initializeElements() {
    this.demoRegisterWrap = $('.demoRegister-wrap');
    this.registrationForm = $('.registration-form');
    this.username = $('#username').value;
    this.useremail = $('#useremail').value;
    this.userpassword = $('#userpassword').value;
    this.formValidation();
  }
  formValidation() {
    let submitBtn = this.demoRegisterWrap.find('.submitBtn');
    submitBtn.on('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      var text = "";
      if (UserName(this.username)) {}
      if (UserEmail(this.useremail)) {}
      if (UserPassword(this.userpassword)) {}
      return false;
    });
    /*Name input validation*/
    function UserName(username) {
      var text = "";
      var message = document.getElementsByClassName("error-message");
      var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
      if (username == "" || username.match(letters)) {
        text = "";
        message[0].innerHTML = text;
        return true;
      } else {
        text = "Name should contain only letters";
        message[0].innerHTML = text;
        return false;
      }
    }


    /*email address input validation*/
    function UserEmail(useremail) {
      var text = "";
      //var useremail = ''; 
      var message = document.getElementsByClassName("error-message");
      var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
      var atpos = useremail.indexOf("@");
      var dotpos = useremail.lastIndexOf(".");

      if (useremail == "" || useremail.match(mailformat) || atpos > 1 && (dotpos - atpos > 2)) {
        text = "";
        message[1].innerHTML = text;
        return true;
      } else {
        text = "Wrong email format";
        message[1].innerHTML = text;
        return false;
      }
    }

    /*validate password*/
    function UserPassword(userpassword) {
      var text = "";
      var message = document.getElementsByClassName("error-message");
      var illegalChars = /[\W_]/;
      if (illegalChars.test(userpassword)) {
        text = "Password contains illegal characters";
        message[2].innerHTML = text;
        return false;
      } else if ((userpassword.search(/[0-9]+/) == -1)) {
        text = "Password should contain at least one number";
        message[2].innerHTML = text;
        return false;
      } else {
        text = "";
        message[2].innerHTML = text;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

}

new Registrationform();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demoRegister-wrap">
  <form class="registration-form" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
      <p class="error-message"></p>
      <input type="text" id="useremail" placeholder="Email" />
      <p class="error-message"></p>
      <input type="password" id="userpassword" pattern=".{8,}" title="8 characters minimum" />
      <p class="error-message"></p>
      <label for="submit"></label>
      <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: replace `.value` with `.val()`

Comment: @RolandStarke i replaced error solved but fields are not validated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current code you are not getting latest value of input so always they are empty .Then , in your function i have interchange condition so that required message get display . Also , i have change from `click` to `submit` and then inside that event handler i have  check if all the function return `true` if yes submit your form  .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
class Registrationform {
  constructor() {
    this.initializeElements();
  }
  initializeElements() {
    this.demoRegisterWrap = $('.demoRegister-wrap');
    this.registrationForm = $('.registration-form');
    this.username = $('#username');
    this.useremail = $('#useremail');
    this.userpassword = $('#userpassword');
    this.formValidation();
  }
  formValidation() {
    let submitBtn = this.demoRegisterWrap.find('.registration-form');
    //on submit...
    submitBtn.on('submit', e => {
      var flag = false;
      //pass here .val() to get lates value of input..
      var status1 = UserName(this.username.val())
      var status2 = UserEmail(this.useremail.val())
      var status3 = UserPassword(this.userpassword.val())
      console.log(status1, status2, status3)
      //if all true...no error ..
      if (status1 && status2 && status3) {
        flag = true; //set true
      }
      return flag; //depdning on this submit your form
    });

    function UserName(username) {
      var text = "";
      var message = document.getElementsByClassName("error-message");
      var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
      //use `!` here 
      if (username == "" || !username.match(letters)) {
        text = "Name should contain only letters"
        message[0].innerHTML = text;
        return false;
      } else {
        text = "";
        message[0].innerHTML = text;
        return true;
      }
    }

    function UserEmail(useremail) {
      var text = "";
      var message = document.getElementsByClassName("error-message");
      var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
      var atpos = useremail.indexOf("@");
      var dotpos = useremail.lastIndexOf(".");
      //use ! here ..
      if (useremail == "" || !useremail.match(mailformat) || atpos > 1 && (dotpos - atpos > 2)) {
        text = "Wrong email format";
        message[1].innerHTML = text;
        return false;

      } else {
        text = "";
        message[1].innerHTML = text;
        return true;
      }
    }

    function UserPassword(userpassword) {
      var text = "";
      var message = document.getElementsByClassName("error-message");
      var illegalChars = /[\W_]/;
      if (illegalChars.test(userpassword)) {
        text = "Password contains illegal characters";
        message[2].innerHTML = text;
        return false;
      } else if ((userpassword.search(/[0-9]+/) == -1)) {
        text = "Password should contain at least one number";
        message[2].innerHTML = text;
        return false;
      } else {
        text = "";
        message[2].innerHTML = text;
        return true;
      }
    }
  }

}

new Registrationform();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="demoRegister-wrap">
  <form class="registration-form" novalidate>
    <fieldset>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="username" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
      <p class="error-message"></p>
      <input type="text" id="useremail" placeholder="Email" />
      <p class="error-message"></p>
      <input type="password" id="userpassword" title="8 characters minimum" />
      <p class="error-message"></p>
      <label for="submit"></label>
      <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working fine but the email field is not validate. if the pass email also getting the error message.

Comment: But , Its working for me just fine . Also , try removing `atpos > 1 && (dotpos - atpos > 2` part i think is not needed as you are already checking that in mailformat .

Answer (score 0):

I would have used the constraint validation if i where u... add some required, minlength, pattern, autocomplete attributes. this way the form validatoin can work without javascript enabled. and needs much less code to work.

HTML is suppose to define the markup/semantics of how the page is built and suppose to work. Javascript is suppose to enhance the experiment.

I would also not use placeholder as labels it's semantically wrong.
placeholder should be examples of correct input.

```html
<div class="demoRegister-wrap">
  <form class="registration-form">
    <fieldset>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" id="username" required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" name="name" placeholder="Name" />
      <p class="error-message"></p>
      <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="useremail" placeholder="Email" />
      <p class="error-message"></p>
      <input type="password" minlength="8" required id="userpassword" autocomplete="new-password" name="password" title="8 characters minimum" />
      <p class="error-message"></p>
      <label for="submit"></label>
      <input class="submitBtn" type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Also it's very stupid to restrict the password to not allow any character to be entered, autocomplete="new-password" is a grate way to suggest strong passwords.
What you are suppose to do afterwards is to salt & hash the password so it's not saved in clear text and only contains a-z after being hashed by some checksum